# Greater than on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is for SQL Server 2012. I have a requirement where I am given values to a `composite primary key` and I need to return all the records that are `greater than` than the given set of values.

For example, if my key columns are `K1, K2 and K3`, and I am given values `A, B, C`, I need to return rows such `(K1 = A and K2 = B and K3 > C) OR (K1 = A and K2 > B) OR K1 > A`.

Is there a simpler way to apply greater than to multiple columns? If possible I want to avoid concatenating string for performance reasons. The solution needs to be fairly generic as I need to apply it to a large number of tables.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but what do you mean by "avoid concatenating strings for performance reasons?"  I don't see any concatention here.  The OR statement you use here would be prepared as part of the execution plan of the stored proc so your performance issues wouldn't come from there.  The bigger issue is that historically, SQL Server doesn't short circuit logic statements and OR clauses typically involve full table scans.  Maybe that's been changed in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What I meant by concatenating of strings is that one option is to create a sortable string out of a composite primary key and then it should be possible to do a greater-than on that string. I was wondering if there is some trick to do this using sorting or OVER clause since I need to return records sorted by the values in the PK anyways. Nothing comes to mind aside from a straight-on comparison in the WHERE clause...